# Datatables (jquery) giving wrong datetime

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have app that is built on top of PHP(laravel 9) and js for frontend. We are using jQuery datatables and I'm encountering problem with dates.

My model's created_at is `06:33 PM` (when priting it out in html, and in DB), but when i use datatables with ajax load then im getting `10:33 PM` as time. Any ideas why and how to prevent this form happening?

Blade's html:

```
<table class="table" id="log_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>IP Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#log_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/admin/login-audits/get",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "created_at" },
        { "data": "user.email" },
        { "data": "user.name" },
        { "data": "role.representing_name" },
        { "data": "ip_address" },
        { "data": "status" },
    ],
    "language": {
        "processing": "Loading. Please wait..."
    },
    "order" : [[0, "desc"]]
});
```

Here is also example of discrepancies:
[image]

My timezone in config/app.php is already set to `America/New_York`

Answer (score 1):

```
columns:[
            {
                data:"created_at",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
return moment.utc(data).local().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: This is helpful, and this is converting any date with `moment` to a local date with a given format. I would like to disable this conversion at all. Or make this permanent for all dates.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what is your timezone?

1. go to **config/app.php**
2. set yout timezone example `'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles'`

   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan view:clear
   php artisan config:cache

Comment: I have that already set up my friend. As you can see my regular print of the database is giving me the correct date. It has to be something with jQuery data tables rendering.